# Is there a way to get notified when a spinner is activated?

Tags: android, spinner

I wish I had a notification when a spinner is activated and the dropdown list is displayed, but I cannot find one. When it is displayed for the first time, I want to change an entry in the list. I am using an ArrayAdapter with the spinner. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if i understand you right.

But just set a flag, like this:

```
boolean isTriggeredBefore = false;
```

And if that is false just use another values for that arrayadapter for e.g

```
if(isTriggeredBefore)
     ArrayAdapter(this, R.array.list, R.id.tv);
else
     ArrayAdapter(this, R.array.listFirstTime, R.id.tv);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: When I create the adapter I use the "firstTimeList", but after that there is no more notification/callback/event (where I could insert my code) until "onItemSelected" is called by the spinner.

Comment: Can't you just set an onClickListener on the spinner?